# only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars When using matlab keys

Tags: python, type-conversion

I'm trying to convert serial date number data in a matlab file to UTC using python.

```
from datetime import *
import scipy.io as sio
import toutc as toutc
from numpy import *
from plotting import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
S = sio.loadmat(*MatLab_File.mat*)
print (S.keys())                    # Time is stored as the key 't'
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
SDN = S[str(input('time'))]         # Establishing we are using the key 't'
X = (datetime.fromordinal(SDN) + timedelta(days=SDN%1) - timedelta(days = 366))
```

This last line returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "matgraph.py", line 19, in <module>
    X = (datetime.fromordinal(SDN) + timedelta(days=SDN%1) - timedelta(days = >366))
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Any idea why this isn't working?

Thank you

Edit: changed '[]' to '()' on last line and updated error to match

Comment: `datetime.fromordinal` is a method, but you are trying to use subscription on it with `[SDN]`. You almost certainly meant to use `datetime.fromordinal(SDN)` instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters you are the boss here, but question: Why is this off-topic? It may not be a typographical mistake, but a honest "I have no idea what I am doing". Shouldn't it deserve an answer?

Comment: @AnderBiguri: see the description of the off-topic reason. This isn't useful for *future visitors*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters If I were to google `TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable` because it happens in my code, and would get here, it would be useful, wouldnt it? My little experience tells me that when someone asks for "what does this specific error happens" those questions have generally lots of views

Comment: @AnderBiguri: there are also [369 Google results on that exact error message](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=builtin_function_or_method+object+is+not+subscriptable+error+site:stackoverflow.com) when limiting this to just SO. This is hardly a researched and helpful question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You are right, already asked too many times. Keep up with the nice work!

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry I'm pretty new to this and I have been trying to research but It seems like a vague (to me) error that I was unable to find a example that i could apply to my situation. sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `fromordinal[SDN]` instead of `fromordinal(SDN)`.

Comment: When i fix that it returns: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Answer (score 0):

The error happens because you are trying to access a function as if it was an array. Remember that square brackets are for accessing values inside an array `[]`, while parenthesis are for functions `()` in python.

`datetime.fromordinal[SDN]` should be `datetime.fromordinal(SDN)`

Comment: when I fix that it returns: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Comment: @LucasGorski: that error too has many google results; you are passing a numpy array to something that doesn't support numpy arrays.

Comment: @LucasGorski: so you'd have to look at what type `SDN` is; is it an array or a numpy-specific type? You'll have to extract or convert then.